# SELECT data filtering by 2 values

Tags: mysql, inner-join

long time since the last time...
Problem here is that: 
One table with (USER) users data (name, phone etc)
Other table (USER_TYPE) which have and id and a Varchar with the type (student,worker etc)
USER has a relationship 1-N with USER_TYPE_USER. USER_TYPE_USER has a relationship 1-N with USER_TYPE. As you can guess, USER_TYPE_USER stores users' ids and user_type id's. One user can be of one or more types.

My problem here is that I want to select user data and user type from users that are type 1 and 2. So I have this (sorry, names are in Spanish).

```
 SELECT socio.*, socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio,tipo_socio.tipo 
 FROM ((respeta.socio 
 INNER JOIN respeta.socio_tipo_socio ON socio.dni = respeta.socio_tipo_socio.socio_dni)
 INNER JOIN respeta.tipo_socio ON tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio)
 WHERE socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = 1 AND socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = 2
```

This doesn't work. I know I can place OR instead AND, but this will give me users which are only type 1 or 2.

Any ideas? Hope my data base professor don't see I'm asking that XD. Thanks

EDIT 1. 
This is another way of make the query (I ask for less data), maybe It helps to understand what I'm trying to accomplish. I have User1 which is type 1 and 2, and User2, which is type 2. I just want to retrieve users who are Type1 and Type2, so, the ideal query will return just User1.

```
 SELECT distinct(socio.dni), socio.nombre
 from socio, socio_tipo_socio, tipo_socio 
 WHERE socio.dni = socio_tipo_socio.socio_dni 
 AND socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio
 AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio  = 2
```

Obviously, that query above, shows type2 users (User1 and User2). Don't know how fix It to say something like "AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio  = 2 AND AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio  = 1" and have only User1. That's where I'm stuck.

EDIT 2

SOLVED!!!! YEYYY!!!

```
 SELECT *
 FROM socio, tipo_socio, socio_tipo_socio
 WHERE tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = 1 
 AND socio.dni IN (
  SELECT socio.dni
  FROM socio, socio_tipo_socio, tipo_socio
  WHERE tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = 2
  AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio
  AND socio.dni = socio_tipo_socio.socio_dni
 )
 AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio
 AND socio.dni = socio_tipo_socio.socio_dni
```

Comment: I see. So you have 1 N-N relation and 1 table to cover N-N relation. 3 tables. And you want only the users who have type1 and type2 . correct?. Is nested queries allowed for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done there logically correct. However none of one single record can have value 1 and value 2 simultaneously. What you should do is finding records with type1, finding records with type2 and merging them.

rows with type1

```
SELECT *
FROM users utu types
WHERE typeid = 1 AND <table connectors>
```

rows with type2

```
SELECT *
FROM users utu types
WHERE typeid = 2 AND <table connectors>
```

rows with type1 only if they are in type2 also

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE typeid = 1 AND IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM users utu types
    WHERE typeid = 2
    ) AND <table connectors>
```

EDIT:
detailed version.

No. you need to use only this.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE typeid = 1 
  AND IN userid (
          SELECT userid
          FROM users utu types
          WHERE typeid = 2
         )
  AND tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio = socio_tipo_socio.id_tipo_socio
  AND socio.dni = socio_tipo_socio.socio_dni
```

first table founds the people with type1.second is findind type2. see th IN in the 3rd query it means that find the people with type1 and IN the type2. It is like array search.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I'm not getting It. Am i supposed to build 3 queries or just the last one? If you can develop a little bit more your answers please, I will be very thankful.

Comment: I edited it. ( <table connector> + FROM table1,table 2 ) is same thing with join. its just more reliable. <table connector> is the same thing s at the JOIN ON <connector>

Comment: Thanks for your time, much appreciated. I'm trying that, but MySql keeps launching error on the AND IN (... part. Is like is the wrong syntax or something like that.

Comment: hehehe no problem, but I still think userid goes between AND & IN. I edit again my question